# Break while loop after one execution? Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, while-loop, break

I'm trying to find the greatest prime number based on a max value...I just want this to print the largest prime number but I can't figure out how to break this loop after printing the first number.

```
require 'prime'

1000.downto(1) do |i| 
  while i.prime? do print i
end
end
```

Comment: You should probably include a tag with a specific programming language.

Comment: Note that in a case where you want to find a single value of a collection you can use [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-find). In your case; `1000.downto(1).find(&:prime?)` would be a clean solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not familiar with ruby but i guess it should work

```
1000.downto(1) do |i| 
    if i.prime? then 
          print i
          break
    end
end
```